# Rebase master to feature branch

Tags: git, rebase

Hello I created a new repo, cloned it, forgot to create a feature branch and started working in master branch. Now I realized and I would like to fix this. I havent committed anything yet. My goal now would be to 'transfer' current changes to feature branch leaving the master completely clean (in a state when repo was cloned). Is there any non-invasive way to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: If you haven't committed, just check out the feature branch. Otherwise, use stash.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is like this

```
$ git checkout cool-feature
$ git rebase master
```

and then merge it in master whenever you want to merge the feature branch to master :

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge cool-feature
```

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do i stash your changes

```
git stash
```

then create new branch

```
git checkout <your new branch name>
```

and to apply your changes

```
git stash apply
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git add . // to add all the changed files to index (so that git 'become aware' of these files
git stash // to "put aside" all the changes that git is aware of
git status // should be empty, since you haven't committed you're in sync with master
git checkout -b  myfeaturebranch // create a branch, after this command you're on feature branch
git stash apply  // apply all the stashed (putted aside) changed to feature branch
```

Comment: Please describe in words why the above set of commands solves the issue. Also, `git checkout -b` needs the name of the new branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't committed anything yet, then from master:

```
git checkout -b <my-new-branch>
git add *
git commit -m "updated"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git rev-parse`, and `git update-ref` to simply change the names of the local and remove branches to protect the guilty.

That is, get the sha1 of the remote origin branch tip (probably origin/master).

Remember the name of the current branch to be renamed `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD` (probably refs/heads/master)

`git checkout -b <newname>`

`git update-ref <oldbranchrefname> <remote_tip>`

You should now have the  as your current branch, and the former branch name reset back to the fetched tip.